# In Angular 2+, how do you specify that the native element should be bound to the template variable if it also has an Angular directive applied to it?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Syntax for Angular 2+ template variables is as follows:

`<someElement #someVariable="someDirective"></someElement>`

where `someElement` is an element tag, `someVariable` is the variable name and `someDirective` is a directive on `someElement` that should be bound to `someVariable`.

If `someDirective` is missing, i.e.

`<someElement #someVariable></someElement>`

and `someElement` is a native HTML element with no Angular directives then `someVariable` will be bound to the `ElementRef` of that element.

But how do I reproduce this behaviour when `someElement` *does* have an Angular directive? How do I specify that I want the `ElementRef` to be bound to the variable and not some directive? As far as I know there is no syntax like

`<someElement #someVariable="element"></someElement>`

(although [proposals exist](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2721)).

My specific use case is that I am trying to obtain the `ElementRef` of the `button` element in this template:

`<button md-raised-button #button>Click me</button>`

where `md-raised-button` is an [Angular Material](http://material.angular.io) directive. But `#button` just binds to `MdButton` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Component you can use `@ViewChild` to read the `ElementRef` of `#button`

```
@ViewChild('button', {read: ElementRef})
public myFancyButton: ElementRef;
```